# is it possible to bock JSON file download partially by allowing only specific pages to use it

Tags: javascript, json, iis

is it possible to bock JSON file download partially by allowing only specific pages to use it.

Example, lets say

> mywebsite.com/folder1/page.asp

can download and use

> mywebsite.com/folder2/page.json

however, any other request to json file (direct or from any other pages) are blocked.

Can it be done on the IIS level? Can it be done on script level?

Comment: you can check the referer, or check `location.href` from within the file and `throw` if it's not cool.

Comment: dies it mean I can put script inside of json file to check the referring page and simply show an empty file? Is there any example of such jnson file I am not pro in JavaScript